# $\alpha$-Quantile for Gamma distribution $\Gamma(n,\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X\sim\Gamma(n,\frac{1}{2})$ and  $\alpha\in(0,1)$. I know that

\begin{align}
P(X\le s)&=\int_0^ s\frac{1}{2^n\Gamma(n)}x^{n-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2(n-1)!}\int_0^s\Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)^{n-1}e^{-\frac{x}{2}}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^{s/2} t^{n-1} e^{-t}dt\\
\end{align}

Now I wonder how can I find $u,v$ such that

$$\frac{\alpha}{2}\ge \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^{u/2} t^{n-1} e^{-t}dt=P(X\le u),$$
$$1-\frac{\alpha}{2} \le \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^{v/2} t^{n-1} e^{-t}dt= P(X\le v)\text{ ?}$$
Maybe there is an easy argument... Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Of course, the integral in the end is the same as in the definition of the Gammafunction.

Comment: If I understand your notation and if you need the answers instead of hints how to do the calculus, then here is R code that will give you the answer for $n = 1, 2, \dots, 50$ and $\alpha = 0.05:$ `n = 1:50;  L = qgamma(.025, n, 2);  U = qgamma(.975, n ,2);
cbind(n, L, U)`. For $n = 1,$ you have the exponential distribution, for which the calculus is trivial. For $n > 200,$ you should get good answers with normal approximation.

Comment: Oh! Do I get you right, that there are these tables in backmatter of statistic books for exactly these kind of questions? :-)

Comment: You might be able to use widely available printed tables of chi-squared distributions (with appriat modifications; halve DF to get gamma shape). Some printed tables have only the upper tail. Look around. If you're allergic to R, I suppose MatLab and such will do much the same computations. // But R is free, devotedly bug free for basic stuff like this, and trivial to install. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). // Code `qchisq(.95, 4)` and `qgamma(.95, 2, 1/2)` both return  9.487729

Comment: Actually one can just take the $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$-quantile by definition(?) or just calculate it like @BruceET did. :-)